# use xlwings to call Python UDFs

Tags: python, settings, xlwings

I'm trying to call two Python UDFs in excel via xlwings, i saw the following error message:
*Make sure that this workbook contains the xlwings module and you are trusting access to the VBA project object module(Options).*

[Macro setting is already enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBH9P.png), the workbook also referenced to xlwings. The xlwings version in Anaconda is 0.20.0, i think this is the latest version, but i can only see "import Python UDFs" button under xlwings Add-in settings, nothing else, which is different from the Add-in settings i saw in some videos. I'm using Jupyter Notebook, my python code is saved in "M:\SolverFunction.ipynb". I also saved the code in .py extension with the same name in the same directory, not sure if i can just use .ipynb extension directly. Below is my function settings in VBA, can someone please check if everything is correct:

```
PYTHON_WIN = "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe"
PYTHON_MAC = ""
PYTHON_FROZEN = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\build\exe.win32-2.7"
PYTHONPATH = "M:\"
UDF_MODULES = "SolverFunction"
UDF_DEBUG_SERVER = False
LOG_FILE = ""
SHOW_LOG = True
OPTIMIZED_CONNECTION = False
```

when i run the macro Run_Python_Function, it shows SyntaxError:
[Syntax Error in Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DE6I.png)

I need to call two python UDFs,don't really know how to fix this error, there is no error in the python code itself.
Another question: in the python code i use 'xw.Book' to call the existing sheet

```
wb = xw.Book(r'M:\SolverFunction.xlsm')
```

If the sheet is saved in another directory with another name, say "C:\Desktop\DVA Totem Submission\xyz.xlsm", except modifying the code

```
wb = xw.Book(r'C:\Desktop\DVA Totem Submission\xyz.xlsm')
```

do i need to change the function settings in VBA as well?
Thanks,